# regex for a specific string

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regex code in an xlsx form for survey123 to match only one of the following scenarios at a time. The field can have one of the following:

```
[1-9]{1,3} or 
[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]{1,3}  or
[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]{1,3};[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]{1,3}
```

with the second part `(;[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]{1,3})` repeated an unspecified number of times.

But I want the `/` and `;` required in the scenarios that they are in and not allowed in the scenarios in which they are not.  My code doesn't work. Can someone help me figure this out?

I have tried `([0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,3}\;[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,3})|([0-9]{1,3})|([0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,3})` in an online tester https://regexr.com/?32jph but I can't get it to match `2/3` or `0/2`

There shouldn't be any leading zeros.

I am counting birds. If the bird species is one that gender is hard to tell apart, I am only counting the total number of birds (1-999). If the species genders can be determined then I record the number of males/females (0/1 or 2/3). When I have more than one group of the same species of which gender can be determined, then I would record male/females;male/females;male/females (0/2;2/3;4/0;1/1) up to the number of groups for that species. When I enter these into survey123 I want the regex to require the correct format.

Examples of acceptable entries are:

```
1  
99  
887 
104  
180  
0/99  
300/0  
2/3  
65/3  
1/2;2/0  
1/2;2/0;9/50;3/2;0/1
```

Comment: I don’t see a question in your post.

Comment: I can't figure the code out to get what I want. I am looking for help to get the outcome specified in the post - @Brien

Comment: You need to specify which language you're working with; the answer for Perl is quite different for the answer for Python, for example, and you're probably not using either of those anyway.

Comment: *My code doesn't work*. Please show what you've tried. Also, you should google search "online regex tester". There are several. They let you trial your regex experiments with immediate results.

Comment: The first pattern is curious.  You don't allow 20, 109, 300 or 550 as valid numbers, even though the other patterns all allow even leading zeros.  Is that intentional or oversight?  Should you be working with `[1-9][0-9]{1,2}` for the 1-3 digit patterns?\]

Comment: I want an integer by itself - 1-9 for up to 3 digits but not with a leading 0. So yes part is an oversight because 309 is acceptable but not 039.

Comment: I mistyped the replacement; it should use `{0,2}` to allow for single digit numbers.  Oops — sorry!  Also, is zero (a single zero) permitted as a number?  Some of your examples with `/` say "yes", but what about for the single number case? You imply not, but you may as well state the requirement.  The extra information should go into the question, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to get the regex to recognize integers 0..999 without leading zeros; the 1..999 variant might be needed for the 'single number' example.

No leading zeros means:

```
[1-9][0-9]{0,2}
```

That excludes 0 (so it covers 1..999).  Adding 0 on its own requires something equivalent to this (there are alternatives that achieve the same result):

```
(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})
```

Now you need to build that into recognizing single numbers; a single pair of numbers 0..999 separated by a slash would be:

```
(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})/(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})
```

And a list of such number pairs separated by semicolons would be:

```
(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})/(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})(;(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})/(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}))*
```

So, the overall regex needs to be:

```
(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})|(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})/(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})(;(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})/(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}))*
```

You can add anchors (e.g. `^` and `$`) as appropriate.  You might need to escape the `/` if your host language insists on `/` surrounding the regular expression.

Converted to Perl and with anchors, allowing space at the start and end of line, but not in the middle, yields:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $qr = qr%
            ^ \s* (
            (0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}) |
            (0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})/(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}) (;(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})/(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}))*
            ) \s* $
            %x;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ m/$qr/)
    {
        print "Matches: $_\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Failed: $_\n";
    }
}
```

That's rather verbose, but moderately clear.  The `qr% … %x` notation compiles a regex spread over multiple lines where spaces in the regex are not significant.  There are lots of capture parentheses in that which should probably be non-capturing, but that's a feature of Perl regexes that isn't necessarily available elsewhere.

Given the sample data:

```
1  
99  
887  
2/3  
65/3  
1/2;2/0  
1/2;2/0;9/50;3/2;0/1
2x/3
elephant
0
0/0
1/2;3/4;7/8;15/16;31/32;63/64;127/128;255/256;511/512
1000
1234/234
234/1234
```

the output is:

```
Matches: 1  
Matches: 99  
Matches: 887  
Matches: 2/3  
Matches: 65/3  
Matches: 1/2;2/0  
Matches: 1/2;2/0;9/50;3/2;0/1
Failed: 2x/3
Failed: elephant
Matches: 0
Matches: 0/0
Matches: 1/2;3/4;7/8;15/16;31/32;63/64;127/128;255/256;511/512
Failed: 1000
Failed: 1234/234
Failed: 234/1234
```

The failures match what I'd expect.  The only mildly controversial line(s) are the `0` and perhaps `0/0` (you only show trailing `0`, not a leading `0`).  The adjustments are easy.

Perl would allow me to use `\d` in place of `[0-9]`; since you've not said what you're using, it isn't clear whether that will work for you.